# Adjusting alpha values based on the number of the tests

Tags: anova

In my studies I frequently perform Two-way ANOVA followed by a post-hoc evaluation, it may be Sidak or Tukey test depending on the number of groups. I use Sidak for 2 groups and Tukey for 3 groups. I often use GraphPAD Prism. I will put my questions separately to facilitate.

- When I do a Sidak or Tukey post-hoc evaluation I need to perform another correction for multiple testing, like the Bonferroni Correction? I read that Sidak and Bonferroni are very similar, but i´m still in doubt.
- Assuming that I don't need to perform another test besides Sidak's (for 2 groups) or Tukey's (for 3 groups) how can I calculate the adjusted alpha value? Graph Pad prism reports an alpha value of 0.05, and also reports the number of families (for example: 1 for Sidak´s and 4 for Tukey´s) and the number of comparisons per family (for example: 4 for Sidaks and 6 for Tukeys). Should I calculate the adjusted alpha value with this information? How?
- Regarding unpaired t-tests, these were performed comparing the means of two groups and no multiple tests were made. Multiple testing corrections needs to be applied?